# Не срабатывает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Новости на странице выводятся в таком виде

[image]

```
<div class="news">
    <div class="news-date">12/01/2004</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="news-text short"><a href="/">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</a> consectetuer adipiscing elit,
        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
        erat volutpat. tUt wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
        ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
        nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        tUt wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
        lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis</div>
    <div class="news-link"><a href="/">&#8226; read more</a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

текст новости в блоке news-text показан не полностью, для этого к нему добавлен класс

```
.short {
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы по клику на ссылку read more класс short удалялся и текст показывался целиком, а текст в ссылке заменялся на collapse, а затем при клике на collapse класс short снова добавлялся, и текст в ссылке обратно заменялся на read more.

Для этого пишу скрипт на jQuery.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("article #news-box .news .news-link").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).closest("article #news-box .news .news-text").removeClass("short");
            jQuery(this).html("&#8226; collapse");
            false;
        },

        function () {
            jQuery(this).closest("article #news-box .news .news-text").addClass("short");
            jQuery(this).html("&#8226; read more");
            false;
        });
</script>
```

но он не срабатывает, при клике на ссылку ничего не происходит. Подскажите, как его поправить, чтобы он работал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, надо использовать toggle, а не click.
Во-вторых, false в конце функций не поможет. Используйте e.preventDefault();
В третьих, closest ищет первый подходящий элемент среди **родительских** элементов. Текст у вас не является родителем.
Вот так будет работать:

```
jQuery("article #news-box .news .news-link a").toggle(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings("article #news-box .news .news-text").removeClass("short");
    jQuery(this).html("&#8226; collapse");
    e.preventDefault();
}, function(e) {
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings("article #news-box .news .news-text").addClass("short");
    jQuery(this).html("&#8226; read more");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```